# Como criptografar um pendrive em C?

Tags: c, criptografia, arduino

Primeiramente para situá-los, estou com uma ideia de segurança, e para conseguir colocar essa ideia em prática eu precisaria aprender a criptografar um pendrive.

A ideia é que o pendrive funcione como uma 'chave', e ao mesmo tempo esse pendrive não pode ser facilmente acessado(por isso a criptografia).

Eu poderia simplesmente usar o BitLocker, ou vários outros programas para criptografia. Mas meu intuito é que o pendrive não possa ser acessado por nenhum sistema operacional 'comum'. Eu quero que o pendrive seja acessado, única e exclusivamente pelo meu hardware(um Arduino por exemplo(que também vou precisar aprender, mas uma coisa de cada vez kk)).

Conheço pouco sobre criptografia, mas se alguem souber, se já passou por situação semelhante e puder me ajudar, me dar uma direção, por onde começar etc.

Obrigado!!

Comment: Grosseiramente falando o que busco mesmo é criptografar o pendrive em sí, não algum arquivo dentro dele.

Comment: Criptografar o pendrive não é um problema. Você pode usar o LUKS pra isso (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup). O problema é você conseguir implementar a descriptografia no Arduino. Ele não tem poder computacional nem bibliotecas pra isso.

Comment: @cantoni obrigado mesmo, entendi seu ponto de vista. Talvez essa não seja a melhor solução então... ainda vou levar mais um tempo 'quebrando a cabeça' para essa solução

Answer (score 4):

Seguem algumas dicas e sugestões:

**1)** Não é só porque a informação não pode ser lida de forma ortodoxa (através de sistemas operacionais comuns) que ela está segura. Isso é chamado de `falsa sensação de segurança`. A melhor maneira de proteger os seus dados é através da criptografia (e de todo poder da matemática por trás dela), uma vez criptografados, não importa o meio ou a mídia no qual esses dados serão trafegados, armazenados e/ou copiados, o que importa é que para serem decriptografados se exigiria um tremendo esforço computacional, muito tempo e/ou muito dinheiro;

**2)** Basicamente, existem 2 tipos distintos de algoritmos criptográficos utilizando chaves: o `Simétrico` e o `Assimétrico`. Para simplificar, sugiro a utilização de um algoritmo de criptografia de chave simétrica. Atualmente, existem vários tais como: `AES`, `Twofish`, `Serpent`, `Blowfish`, `CAST5`, `RC4`, `3DES` e/ou `IDEA`, e não será difícil encontrar bibliotecas em C capazes de implementa-los;

**3)** Seu *hardware* poderá trabalhar tranquilamente utilizando um sistema de arquivos padrão, tal como o `NTFS`, e fazer a leitura e a gravação de arquivos de forma simples e descomplicada utilizando o hardware do arduino;

**4)** Se a intenção é armazenar a chave criptográfica no *pen-drive*, sugiro que ela seja protegida por um `PIN` (Número de Identificação Pessoal), e isso poderia também ser feito através de criptografia de chave simétrica, com uma chave fácil de ser memorizada. Sugiro o uso de uma biblioteca de compactação (tal como a *zlib*) que seja capaz de compactar e proteger os dados com uma senha, tal como nos cartões de crédito com *chip*;

**5)** Em sistemas *nix, o dispositivo de *pen-drive* é representado por um arquivo especial dentro do diretório `/dev`. Por exemplo: `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, etc. Tal arquivo pode ser aberto por meio da função `open()` enquanto a leitura e gravação dos dados podem ser feitas por meio das funções `read()` e `write()` respectivamente. Uma outra alternativa seria a utilização da função `ioctl()` para a manipulação direta do dispositivo USB.

**Referências:**

PIN:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identification_number

Criptografia Simétrica:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_chave_sim%C3%A9trica

Criptografia Assimétrica:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptografia_de_chave_p%C3%BAblica

Função: `ioctl()`:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html

Função: `open()`:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação, vou dar uma lida nesse material. No entanto, o que busco mesmo é criptografar o pendrive em sí, não algum arquivo dentro dele.

Comment: @EvandroSilva: Segue edição com a inclusão do item 5.

Comment: Hmmm interessante, vou dar uma olhada nessa função ioctl(), talvez seja o que eu procuro. Obrigado pelo material!

Comment: Ótima resposta, @Lacobus! Gostaria de acrescentar que como o pendrive será acessado somente pelo Arduino, não seria necessário um sistema de arquivos, embora toda a gerência da alocação e leitura teria que ser feita manualmente. Se o Arduino suportar a criptografia + sistema de arquivos, não há problema. Senão, pode-se utilizar o pendrive para gravar dados de forma binária (por registros de tamanho fixo, por exemplo) sem respeitar um sistema de arquivos.